# Pulseaudio does not detect built in analog audio, only HDMI from NVidia

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, sound, permissions, pulseaudio

I'm at **Ubuntu 16.04 LTS**

A workaround to this problem is to go to `/tmp` at your home directory and using `chown` for the pulsaudio temporary folder to be under your username. but apparently, these folders are not supposed to be chowned because it was created by system/root.

does anyone know a proper solution or a better suggestion to this problem?

Thanks a lot!

update:

running `alsamixer -c 1` gives me HDA Intel as the card and Realtek ALC1150 as the chip, which are both correct; my master is turned on and has a volume of 73. headphone is muted. S/PDIF is muted.

result for `lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Audio`:

```
00:03.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller [8086:0c0c] (rev 06)
  Subsystem: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller [8086:2010]
  Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
  Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Controller [8086:8ca0]
  Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd 9 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Controller [1458:a0b2]
  Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
  Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:0fba] (rev a1)
   Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device [1458:368e]
   Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
```

result for `aplay -l`:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****

card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC1150 Analog [ALC1150 Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1: ALC1150 Digital [ALC1150 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

card 2: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

card 2: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

card 2: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

card 2: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

result for`pactl list short sinks`:

```
0   auto_null   module-null-sink.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   RUNNING
```

Comment: @DavidFoerster thanks for the help David. I have just updated the question with the output.

Comment: Could you please remove (or rename) `~/.pulse/default.pa`, if it exists, and restart PulseAudio (`pulseaudio -k; pulseaudio --start --log-target=stderr`)? What's the output of the PulseAudio start command? Does the output of `pactl list short sinks` change?

Comment: This question is over a year old. I saw you signed on yesterday (Aug 11 2018). Could you accept an answer below or critique them on how/why they aren't working? Alternatively could you update your question or add your own answer? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a hack (temporary solution), if you are just unable to solve it.

**Disable pulseaudio by editing** `/etc/pulse/client.conf`
(Just killing is not enough because it will keep restarting.)

Uncomment (remove `#` from in front of) and edit

```
autospawn = no
```

Now you can kill pulseaudio.

```
$ pulseaudio --kill
```

That's it.

*Double check that it has not auto spawned by running:*

```
$ ps cax | grep pulseaudio
```

If its still running, then do

```
$ systemctl --user stop pulseaudio.socket && systemctl --user stop pulseaudio.service
```

***Now your analog audio should start working.***

To be able to change volume, reassign your volume keys (or any kbd shortcut of your choice) to:

```
amixer set Master 5%+    
amixer set Master 5%-
```

Any time you need to  re-enable pulseaudio to redirect audio to somewhere else, like when using a bluetooth headphone, do.

```
$ pulseaudio --start
```

And then restart whatever media app you were using. Now audio from motherboard will stop and bluetooth will start playing (check using pavucontrol).

Make alias like 'pas' and 'pak' or kbd shortucuts to quickly start and stop pulse.

Answer (score 2):

Lately I had a problem with Xonar soundcard caused by HDMI soundcard integrated in my Radeon GPU.

For me blacklisting intel and hdmi modules, preventing them from being loaded by ALSA, fixed the problem.

To do this, simply add these 2 lines at the beginning of the `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` file:

```
blacklist snd_hda_intel
blacklist snd_hda_codec_hdmi
```

Then reboot PC and see if it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Your tests show that your hardware and driver modules are working correctly and audio is ready to be used. But it looks as if something else took sole control of the analog card before pulseaudio could claim it.

Check using:

```
sudo fuser -v /dev/snd/*
sudo fuser -v /dev/dsp
```

Now uninstall that, restart and check.

If you did not find anything then a common culprit is 'timidity' (I think kde-full installs it). Remove just its daemon (can't remove timidity itself as its a dependency).

```
sudo aptitude purge timidity-daemon
```

Now restart and check.

If its still unsolved you will have to try the hard way, remembering what you installed that could be using your audio and try uninstalling it and restarting.

This kind of pulse/alsa problem, though it seems simple is quite difficult to solve unless we have spent a lot of time troubleshooting and 'understand' the problem. So do persist or use a temporary hack till you have the time.